# Get content in the middle of the string using RegEx

Tags: php, regex, string

I have string, which looks like this:

> Здравствуйте,
>      Мы – Добропочта. Для Вас есть анонимное письмо:
>        ------------------------------
>
> {MESSAGE}
>      
>        ------------------------------
>      Добропочта не несет ответственности за передаваемую информацию,
>      Добропочта не создает данные сообщения.
>      С уважением, Добропочта.

*`{MESSAGE}` -- here is content which I need to get

If I'm trying to do this using `chop()` it cuts more chars than needed, if I use `str_ireplace`, it isn't replacing at all
I can't understand how to make this right

Comment: @anubhava in {MESSAGE} could be any text, i've tried to match it by exploding via {MESSAGE} and then removing this two parts of string

Comment: Is the {MESSAGE} always proceeded by a row of dashes followed by a blank line, and is it always followed by a blank line followed by a row of dashes?

Answer (score 1):

```
$subject = "------------------------------\n\nMessage\nmessage line2\n\n------------------------------";
$pattern = '/(?s)-{30}\n\n(.*?)\n\n-{30}/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Replace `$subject` with your string.
`$matches[1]` will contain your message.
I am assuming there are always exactly 30 dashes

Explanation:
`(.*?)` creates a group. The content of your input string that matches that group can be accessed in `$matches[1]`. If you had more than one group, they would be in successive elements of the $matches array.